# R: what's difference between ALL and all in merge()?

Tags: r, merge, uppercase, lowercase

Tried the example in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html.
Then I found when we set ALL = TRUE and all = TRUE as merge()'s parameter, I just got different outcome (one has 6 rows and another has 7 rows).
What happened? Can anyone give some hints? Thanks.

```
> authors <- data.frame(
+     surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
+     nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
+     deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))
> books <- data.frame(
+     name = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney",
+                "Ripley", "Ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
+     title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
+               "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
+               "LISP-STAT",
+               "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
+               "Interactive Data Analysis",
+               "An Introduction to R"),
+     other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
+                      "Venables & Smith"))

> m1<-merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name", ALL = TRUE)
> m1
   surname nationality deceased                         title other.author
1   McNeil   Australia       no     Interactive Data Analysis         <NA>
2   Ripley          UK       no            Spatial Statistics         <NA>
3   Ripley          UK       no         Stochastic Simulation         <NA>
4  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT         <NA>
5    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis         <NA>
6 Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...       Ripley
> m2<-merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name", all = TRUE)
> m2
   surname nationality deceased                         title     other.author
1   McNeil   Australia       no     Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
2   R Core        <NA>     <NA>          An Introduction to R Venables & Smith
3   Ripley          UK       no            Spatial Statistics             <NA>
4   Ripley          UK       no         Stochastic Simulation             <NA>
5  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT             <NA>
6    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis             <NA>
7 Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...           Ripley
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are observing this behavior is that `ALL` is not a valid argument for `merge` (it is lower case `all`). If you specify `ALL = TRUE`, `merge` does not throw an error because it allows additional arguments via `...`. In your case the argument is ignored. So when you set `ALL = TRUE`, `merge` just uses the default, which is `all = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also considering this issue, but I didn't see any warning like "ALL=TRUE" is not used or ignored, so I was guessing there is something else happened.